# How to get second __init__.py execute for same namespace

Tags: python, python-2.7, namespaces, package, python-import

Here is my directory structure

```
.
|-- path1
|   `-- mynms
|       |-- __init__.py
|       `-- app1
|           |-- __init__.py
|           `-- foo.py
|-- path2
|   `-- mynms
|       |-- __init__.py
|       `-- app2
|           |-- __init__.py
|           `-- bar.py
`-- user.py
```

File contents:

```
$ cat user.py
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
sys.path.append('path1')
sys.path.append('path2')

from mynms.app2.foo import foo
from mynms.app2.bar import bar

foo()
bar()

$ cat path1/mynms/__init__.py;echo ==============;cat path2/mynms/__init__.py
from pkgutil import extend_path
__path__ = extend_path(__path__, __name__)

print "I am path1/mynms/__init__.py"
==============
from pkgutil import extend_path
__path__ = extend_path(__path__, __name__)

print "I am path2/mynms/__init__.py"

$ cat path1/mynms/app1/foo.py; echo ============; cat path2/mynms/app2/bar.py
def foo():
  print "foo!"
============
def bar():
  print "bar!"
```

**Question: When I run user.py, I get only the output of path1/__init__.py but not for path2. Is there some way to fix that?**

```
$ ./user.py
I am path1/mynms/__init__.py        -----> Why is 'I am path2/mynms/__init__.py not printed?
foo!
bar!
```

Comment: You have two packages with the same name which is generally frowned upon. Any reason why your test case package has to be the same name? Can you just rename that second one?

Comment: the name `testcase` is misleading, let me change it.

Comment: I can't change them to different namespaces for other reasons. They are two apps by same dev team but has to stay in different hierarchy for deployment purposes.

Comment: Python 2 does not support namespaced packages out of the box. `setuptools` does add namespace support, but to replicate that behaviour requires extensive hacking. I can summarise what `setuptools` does at some point when I have more time, but you may as well use it directly to package up your projects and have `setuptools`  manage the namespacing *for* you.

Answer (score 3):

When you write `import mynms.app2.foo` or `from mynms.app2.foo import foo`, Python does this:

- import `mynms` by looking for the file `mynms/__init__.py`, which it finds in `path1`
- import `mynms.app1` by looking for a file `mynms/app1/__init__.py` (or `mynms/app1.py`)
- import `mynms.app1.foo` by looking for `mynms/app1/foo.py` (or `mynms/app1/foo/__init__.py`)

On the next import statement, `import mynms.app2.bar`, Python does:

- import `mynms` - it's already imported so there's nothing to do. (You can check `sys.modules['mynms']` to see whether it is already imported. If it isn't, it will raise `KeyError`.)
- import `mynms.app2` - again, this is already imported.
- import `mynms.app2.bar` by reading the file `mynms/app2/bar.py`, which is in `path2`

There's no (sensible) way for Python to import the `mynms` module twice from two different files.

If you have initialisation code you will need to put them in the modules `mynms.app1` and `mynms.app2` so they have different names. i.e. the files `mynms/app1/__init__.py` and `mynms/app2/__init__.py`.

Answer (score 1):

As Martijn Pieters has already mentioned in comments, Python 2 does not support packages distributed as a collection of packages. But you can emulate such packages if you use `setuptools` (most probably you do).

The only problem is that the packages should have correct metainformation, so that `setuptools` could join several subpackages in a virtual single package. The information is usually passed to `setup()` function in `setup.py` and lives in your `site-packages` directory after the installation. That means that those who distribute the packages should anyway make something to properly prepare them, and you can hardly just put them in `PATH` to make them work.

[Here](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#namespace-packages) is the link to the corresponding documentation. Be ready to spend some time, because PEAK documentation is not always enough for a quick start.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the rest of the comments - this is bad code structure and should be refactored ASAP. However, if you really, really, really can't or can't *yet*, then you can muck with the import internals by using the imp module in the standard library:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html

For example, you can import a file not in your normal python module search path by doing something like:

/Users/me/test.py:

```
def run_foo():
  print "hi got here"
```

and another script:

```
import imp
foo = imp.load_source("foo", "/Users/me/test.py")
foo.run_foo()
```

Again, you're working against Python doing it this way, not with it. But it is a good trick to know.